# Grep specific fields from the output of "sysstat"

Tags: linux, unix, awk, grep

How can I grep only the numbers from time and the %idle column?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ErpM0.jpg

these results are from *sysstat*

I want it to look like

```
Time        $idle
4:02:58 AM   100.00
4:02:59 AM   100.00
   .           .
   .           .
   .           .
```

My attempts so far have been with awk is:

```
#!/bin/sh
while true
do
cpu0=$(sar 1 1 | awk '{print $1, $9}')
echo $cpu0 >> test.file
        sleep 4
done
```

however, it gives me

```
Linux 04:02:58 %idle 04:02:59 100.00 Average:
```

if I add \n after $9, it gives me syntax error...

or is there any other way to do it? without using grep or awk?
Thank you

Comment: replace the `echo $cpu0` with `echo "$cpu"` to maintain line breaks

Comment: it prints nothing now :(

Comment: sorry, should be "$cpu0". The quotes are the important bit.

Comment: How can I print only the numbers? and leave the time and %idle at the top?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just awk:

```
awk 'NR==1{ print "Time\t\t"$9 } NR>1{ print $1,$2"\t"$9 }' input.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

awk to the rescue...

```
awk -vOFS="\t" 'NR==1{$1="Time";$2=""} {print $1,$2,$9}'
```

Comment: This misses the AM/PM field